# Чтение текста из файла в веб-элемент Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Здравствуйте! 
На сайте есть поле для ввода текста. Есть файл текст из которого надо ввести в это поле. Как организовать мгновенный ввод текста в это поле?

```
extend = open(r"C:\Var\extend.txt", encoding='utf-8')
str = extend.read()
driver.find_element_by_name('payload').send_keys(str)
```

Не очень помог, т.к. в этом случае текст начинает вводиться построчно, а в файле 3000+ строк, получается ждать нужно несколько минут.
Понимаю, что косяк в `send_keys`.

Comment: Вряд ли бы вы сами вводите огромный текст вручную? Скорее бы ввели волшебную комбинацию: Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V

Comment: Правильно, этот текст я не ввожу в ручную. То есть вы предлагаете после запуска браузера/перехода на нужную страницу, открывать файл, выделять весь текст, копировать его и вставлять в нужное поле? Нет, это не выход. Если в вышеупомянутом коде прописать просто print(str), то консолька мгновенно выведен текст, что хранится в памяти. Вот я бы хотел так же, только не в консоль, а в элемент.

Comment: вы пробовали: `.setAttribute("value", text)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pyperclip # pip install pyperclip
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

main_url = 'https://pastebin.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('ChromeDriver.exe')

def copy_input_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        pyperclip.copy(file.read()) # открываем и копируем содержимое файла

def main(file_path):
    copy_input_data(file_path)
    driver.get(main_url)
    # вставляем текст с буфера обмена
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="paste_code"]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
    sleep(5) # sleep для того чтобы увидеть результат
    driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('text.txt')
```

То же самое что Вам предложили в комментариях, но автоматизированно.

Comment: `def main(file_path, main_url ):` тогда так.

Comment: @nick_gabpe ну да, будет правильнее :)

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="paste_code"]')` можно заменить на `driver.find_element_by_id('paste_code')`