# Построчное копирование из файла. Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, автоматизация

Подскажите, как копировать данные из файла построчно?
Задача: Мне нужно создать чек-лист в Test-IT, заголовки тест-кейсов есть (более 2000 тестов), хочу автоматизировать с помощью selenium webdriver.

Скрипт простой:

1. Скопировать первую строчку из файла
2. Клик "Добавить тест-кейс"
3. Вставить из буфера - в поле "Название кейса"
4. Нажать "Сохранить"
5. Скопировать вторую строку из файла и т.д.

В этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745897/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-selenium) решали похожую задачу, вот ответ

```
import pyperclip # pip install pyperclip
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

main_url = 'https://pastebin.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('ChromeDriver.exe')

def copy_input_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        pyperclip.copy(file.read()) # открываем и копируем содержимое файла

def main(file_path):
    copy_input_data(file_path)
    driver.get(main_url)
    # вставляем текст с буфера обмена
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="paste_code"]').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
    sleep(5) # sleep для того чтобы увидеть результат
    driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('text.txt')
```

может сделать цикл? Пронумеровать строки и обращаться к строке с номером n+1